# Installed Oracle XE 11.2. How do I create a database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I'm new to Oracle, so please bear with me.

I recently installed [Oracle XE Release 11.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/xe-prior-releases-5172097.html) on a Windows 2008 Server that we have. The installation was successful. During installation, I was asked to set a password for `sys`, and I did that. Also, the `HTTP` port used was 8085.

So now I'm trying to create a new database. I have Toad Data Point, but I'm not sure how to connect to the server or how to create the database.

In a browser, I went to *http://OurServer:8085/* but it asks for password. I tried logging in with *sys*, but it doesn't let me. I also tried logging in using my company userid (the one I use to log on to my Windows PC), but it didn't work either.

What else can I do?

Comment: The database is created during installation. See the documentation on how to start it, if you need to: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm - regarding the home page - try opening it from the start menu item that's created for you, as documented in the Getting Started Guide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 11 does not use containers so you already have a database and the default users such as sys and system and all the other oracle built in users.

Go to Computer Management/Local Users and Groups and verify that the group ora_dba exists.
Assuming this is a development project add your regular windows username to the ora_dba group. Now you can log on as sysdba using these steps:

- open a command window
- enter SET ORACLE_SID=XE
- enter sqlplus / as sysdba

This should get you logged on as sys which you should not do normally.  For this one time create a user and grant them a role.

```
CREATE USER < your new user name > IDENTIFIED BY < your new password >;
GRANT DBA to < your new user name>;
```

Then enter exit to close the session.  Log on as your new user using Toad and you should be good to go.

I note that the operating system and database are out of support and you would be better off using the new 18xe on linux.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name of the database since I haven't created one yet. How can I set ORACLE_SID without the name?

Comment: @rbhat  You do have an Oracle instance which is called XE. That is the hard coded SID for the version you are using

Comment: The SID for XE can only be XE.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then. This is the screenshot of the connection manager in Toad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V52WD.png. I get error `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel`

Comment: I know the SID is `XE` because it's specified in `StartDB.bat`. But for some reason I cannot connect to it from my PC.

Comment: I was able to connect to XE, but using port 1521.

Comment: @rbhat that is the default oracle port and hard coded, I believe, for XE

Comment: Thanks again. I wasn't aware I had to use the listener port. I was always typing in the HTTP port.